# What are the .hi and .o files generated by GHC (on Linux)?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am just getting started with Haskell and functional programming in general. After compiling and running my first Haskell program, I noticed that GHC (on Linux) generates three separate files from a single .hs source file: a .hi file, a .o file, and finally an executable. What is the purpose of each of these files? Practically, when are .hi and .o files actually used?

From my little experience in C, I think .o is an object file. Searching Google shows that .hi is an "interface file".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `.o` is exactly the same as C's object files; the `.hi` file is an "interface file"; it contains information about the `.o` that GHC would need, if you compile other modules, to be able to link against that `.o` file (said information cannot be stored in a standard `.o` file).

You could say that the `.hi` file is the equivalent of C's header files (that is, with `.h` extension), only these are generated by GHC from the original Haskell source.

Thus, the `.hi` is used when GHC compiles other modules, and the `.o` is used when linking all modules together to produce the executable.

You can safely delete the `.hi` and `.o` files once you have successfully generated the executable (or keep them if you want to make some small change and rebuild quickly - it will save time in unneeded recompilations).

Comment: Does that mean I can link the .o files generated by GHC to a C program?

Comment: The C compiler isn't aware of the specifics of how GHC represents Haskell code as executable code, so basically, no - what you want there is to use GHC's FFI interface to explicitly declare how to get Haskell and C to interact.

Comment: More precisely: the code generated by GHC in an `.o` is not, by default, ready to be called from C. If you use a `foreign export` directive (see GHC manual), then the `.o` file will contain functions that can be called from C. You can always *link* a GHC produced `.o` file into a C program—object files are object files no matter what's in them. The question is whether the C program can *use* any of the code in that object file.

Answer (score 5):

`.o` files are indeed object files.  Basically chunks of bytecode ready to be linked together.

`.hi` files are interface files.  The short version is that they hold something like compiled type signatures along with information that lets GHC perform optimization across file boundaries.

---

I personally find having these files in my working directory annoying enough that I add `-outputdir ../tmp` to my `ghc` invocation.

Comment: what about .p_hi and .dyn_hi?  My ghc generates for every .hi file them too.

Comment: Hi Daneel, I answered your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67608774/163177