# What is difference between .hi .p_hi and .dyn_hi files generated by GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to reduce size of an archive containing Nix derivations. I noticed that every module has 3 files hi, p_hi and dyn_hi all similar size.

ghc (hint) interpreter requires only hi and if I remove rest variations nothing happens.

So are p_hi and dyn_hi kind of sand bags?

Comment: If you don't want the interface files for profiling and dynamic linking, why did you tell GHC to compile the libraries to support profiling and dynamic linking?

Comment: Are you talking about `.p_hi` and `.dyn_hi` files for external packages installed by Nix, or are you talking about files generated for your own modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `.hi` files are interface definitions for the associated `.o` object files. Older versions of GHC could only work with one version at a time.  This caused issues when a library needed profiling information or dynamic linking as the library would need to be compiled with the new options each time.

To solve this issue GHC added additional functionality that let it have separate object and interface files installed alongside each other.

The `.p_*` files are compiled with profiling enabled.  The `.dyn_*` are compiled to enable dynamic linking.